# Frame elements/controls not interactable

Tags: c#, wpf, frame, code-behind, windows-mui

I have mui:ModernFrame that gets loaded with usercontrols when certain buttons are clicked;

Button

```
<Button Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Frame}" x:Name="HeadWidget" FontSize="14" Margin="0,10,0,3" Content="Head Widget" Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" />
```

Frame

```
<mui:ModernFrame x:Name="Frame" Source="/Pages/Projects/Views/Overview.xaml" Panel.ZIndex="999999" />
```

Code behind to update Frame (on button click)

```
EditPage.CommandParameter = "/Pages/Projects/Views/Edit/Pages/EditPages.xaml#" + valueFromPage1;
```

Which works well, even animates the new content into the frame, but the elements/items (ie buttons, TextBoxes etc) inside the UserControl that is loaded into the frame are not focus-able or clickable.

Any reason why this would be the case, I have tried adding buttons in the demo of the FirstFloor mui ModernFrame sample and has the same effect

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the loaded UserControl that is being loaded into the frame

has buttons with the

```
Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage"
```

function but not present in the code behind as per below;

```
//Once this added, the buttons become interactive (clickable)
ButtonPage.CommandParameter = "/Pages/Projects/Views/Create.xaml";
```